# Why should the sat-temp of refrigerant be below the required temp of the cooled compartment?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have a question about the refrigerant's pressure in the inlet of an evaporator. Why should the sat-temp of the refrigerant be below the required temp of the cooled compartment ? Shouldn't the refrigerant's temp at the exit of the evaporator be equal to that of the cooled compartment ?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

In order for heat transfer to occur, there must be a temperature gradient. If the temperature of the refrigerant was equal to the temperature of the cooled compartment, no heat would flow from the cooled compartment into the refrigerant to drive the phase change.

This is the reason that convective flow over the evaporator coils is important - it increases the rate of heat transfer by keeping the fluid moving so that the temperature right next to the evaporator coil is always close to the average compartment temperature. A larger ${\Delta}T$ leads to a faster rate of heat flow.